# How to read config.js file to set base href in my index.html file in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react app where i have config.js file in my public folder.This files contains environment specific variables.In my public folder we have a "env" folder where we have config.dev.js and config.prod.js files.During CD we are replacing config.js file content with config.dev.js/config.prod.js depending on the environment we are deploying.

I want to set my `<base href="" />` with the respective environment basename in my index.html file.For example
for dev it should look like `<base href="/dev-myapp"/>` and for prod it should look like
`<base href="/prod-myapp" />`.

How to read environment variable(REACT_APP_BASENAME) from config.js file in my index.html file?

Comment: Refer: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#referencing-environment-variables-in-the-html

Comment: @ShriHariL my environment variables are there in config.js file not in .env file, this solution is not working.I tried <base href="%REACT_APP_BASENAME%/" but thats not working

Comment: @RohitSahu Did you try {process.env.customKey}